# javascript function does work properly

Tags: javascript

i am new in javascript world and trying to build a simple function which will work with a callback funciton. here is the code :

```
function add(a,b,c, callback) {


  var arr = [];
  if(callback != 'function') {

    for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length;i++)  {

    arr[i] = arguments[i]*2;
    }

  }
    else {

    for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length-1;i++)  {

    arr[i] = callback(arguments[i]*2);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

function add1 (something) {

  return something + 1;
```

I wanted to run this code as add(1,3,4) or add(1,3,4,add1). but callback function is not working. every time it goes inside the if statement. can anybody tell me why add(1,3,4,add1) is not working ??

Comment: `callback != 'function'` did you mean `typeof callback != 'function'`

Comment: ya... but why is not working if i just use callback != 'function instead of typeof callback != 'function' ?

Comment: do you pass in the fourth argument as the string `'function'`?

Comment: The code seems to work as-is for me. I had to add a closing }, but then it returned the array with the arguments multiplied by 2 in both scenarios. I used `console.log(add(3,2,1,add1))` in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxcLaab0/). You'll have to open the Console in your browser to see the results.

Comment: if i put console.log (callback) after 'function add(a,b,c) { ' it shows undefined. so why do i need to use typeof while javascript already knows callback is undefiend when i try to run add(a,b,c). in that case it should not go inside if statement and should execute else , am i right

Comment: currently, the only way the `callback` will be attempted (and fail) is if you pass in the string `'function'` as the fourth argument ... of course the string `'function'` isn't a function, therefore `callback(arguments[i]*2);` will fail - because `callback` will be the string `'function'` ... now, when calling `add(1,3,4, add1)` the if condition is true (because the function `add1` isn't the string `'function'`) so, you'll end up with an array `[2,6,8,NaN]` - because 2 * an actual function is not a number

Answer (score 0):

The only time the argument `callback` will equal the string `function` is if you pass, as argument 4, the string `'function'` ... of course, that would cause the else code to fail, because `'function'` is not a function

Therefore, in your case, the condition is ALWAYS true, because you pass a function, not the string "function" as the fourth argument

So, your code, in the case of `add(1,3,4,add1)` will return

```
[2, 6, 8, NaN]
```

The NaN is the result of trying to multiply a function by 2 - which is **N**ot **A** **N**umber

By changing the `if` condition to

```
if (typeof callback != 'function')
```

You'll get the droids you are looking for

```js
function add(a, b, c, callback) {

  var arr = [];
  if (typeof callback != 'function') {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

      arr[i] = arguments[i] * 2;
    }
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {

      arr[i] = callback(arguments[i] * 2);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

function add1(something) {

  return something + 1;
}
console.log(add(1, 3, 4));
console.log(add(1, 3, 4, add1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof callback != 'function')
```

Change your if statement as above. Since you just put *callback != 'function'*, JavaScript will find the variable or a property of an object, named 'callback' and try to compare its value with the string value, 'function'.

When you call add(1,3,4), which doesn't have callback as a parameter, of course if statement will return false, because the paremeter *callback* has 'undefined' by default. However, what if you wanted to pass a callback function as the parameter? Like add(1,3,4, add1)

```
// The arguments when you call add(1,3,4,add1)
▼Arguments(4)
 0: 1
 1: 3
 2: 4
 3: f add1(something)
```

This cold will give you a wrong data in here:

```
// When i equals 3, arguments[3] * 2 will not work properly, since it's not a number type
if(callback != 'function'){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        arr[i] = arguments[i] * 2;
    }
}
```

Even though you think you passed the add1 function as the parameter, if statement will only just compare the value of 'callback' with the string value, 'function', it is not working as you thought. **So, to make it right, you have to let JavaScript know whether *callback* 's type is a function or not, by using 'typeof'**

Comment: thank you very much. i got it now. whenever i am sending a function its not a 'function' anymore and its holding the whole definition of function .